# How to update Data Segment Selector in Protected mode

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, gdt

I want to update Data Segment selector to point to some other entry in GDT. But Since I am very new to assembly, I can not do it in my code. However I have updated the Code Segment Selector by using following assembly instruction:

```
ljmp $(GDT_TABLE_INDEX), $(1f)     //This instruction simply points code segment to some other entry in GDT and move to next label.
```

Is there some similar or alternative instruction to update Data Segment Selector also ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the data segment selector using the `mov` instruction.  For example, if you want to set `ds` to `0x1234`, use:

```
mov $1234, %ax
mov %ax, %ds
```

Note that there is no `mov imm, sreg` instruction, so you first have to move the selector's number into a general purpose register.  You might also find it convenient to `pop` into a segment register:

```
push $1234
pop %ds
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really helpful.